# How to switch to another camera in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, camera, workflow

This might have already been asked but how do I switch cameras in blender game engine? What I would like is to play a camera sequence perhaps a panning view around a map and then towards the end switch to a camera linked to my player modal for a third person setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [scene actuator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/scene.html) allows you to alter the active camera.

[image: scene actuator choices]

Comment: Hi sambler, I am here again to bring trouble for you. I have an issue regarding activating cameras. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/changing-active-camera-will-yield-an-incorrect-rendering)? It seems that I am doing everything correctly but the result that I get is so weirdly strange. I need some urgent help and I think you might be able to help me with it. Really appreciate you.

Answer (score 2):

As @sambler answer you can use a scene actuator.
Also you can do it with a script.

```
from bge import logic


locPoint = scene.objects['EmptyPanningEnd'].worldPosition
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
cam1 = scene.objects['panningCamera']
cam2 = scene.objects['playerCamera']

if locPoint != cam1.worldPosition:
    scene.active_camera = cam1
else:
    scene.active_camera = cam2
```

Also if you want to change the camera pressing a key and you have a lot of cameras, add a property and named camera (in each camera).

```
from bge import logic

own = logic.getCurrentController().owner
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
camList = [cam for cam in scene.objects if 'camera' in cam.getPropertyNames()]

if logic.keyboard.events[events.CKEY] == logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    change_camera(scene,camList)

def change_camera(scene, camList):     
    if camList.index(scene.active_camera) < (len(camList) -1):
        scene.active_camera = camList[camList.index(scene.active_camera) + 1]
    else:
         scene.active_camera = camList[0]
```

[Related Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=active%20camera#bge.types.KX_Scene.active_camera)