# How to keyframe the active camera with Python?

Tags: python, animation, camera, keyframes

I'm trying to change the active camera with Python at certain keyframes. An example: render using camera A from frames 1 to 10 and with camera B from 11 to 20, so there would have to be a keyframe at frame 1 and 11.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
cameras = [c for c in bpy.context.scene.objects if c.type == 'CAMERA']

for i, cam in enumerate(cameras):
    scene.camera = cam
    scene.keyframe_insert(data_path="camera", frame=i)
```

But this raises the following error:

> TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "camera" not
> animatable

Note I'm not talking about the Blender game engine like [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162804/bge-how-to-change-active-camera-with-python) was.

Comment: You can't directly animate this property but you can bind cameras to specific markers. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43773/86891

Comment: @Gorgious That did the trick, thank you!